# Woocommerce - Remove add to cart button when user is the product author

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the Add to Cart button when Current user is the logged in user and add the Edit Product link. But this is totally breaking my design and not working:

- Showing only 2 of 12 products
- It keeps showing the Add to Cart button in the first product

  ```
  <?php
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'btn_edit_own_product', 10 );

  function btn_edit_own_product() {
      edit_post_link('Edit Product');
  }
  }
  ?>
  ```

Any help?
Thanks!!

Comment: whre are you placing this code? is this the code as is or just part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
/* remove add-to-cart from shop page for product author  */
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','user_filter_addtocart_for_shop_page') ;
function user_filter_addtocart_for_shop_page(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID());
    if($user_id == $author_id){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }
}

/* remove add-to-cart from single product  page for product author  */
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','user_filter_addtocart_for_single_product_page') ;
function user_filter_addtocart_for_single_product_page(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID());
    if($user_id == $author_id){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more details visit,

[woocommerce- hide add to cart button for product author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552404/woocommerce-hide-add-to-cart-button-for-product-author/34553220#34553220)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code instead. Place this on your current theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'custom_woocommerce_shop_loop' );

function custom_woocommerce_shop_loop() {

    global $post;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );;
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'btn_edit_own_product', 10 );

    }
}
function btn_edit_own_product() {
    edit_post_link('Edit Product');
}
```